# Finding duplicate export in MEF

Tags: prism, mef

I am using MEF and have a duplicate export in my composition container. When I do the following I can see the duplicate.

```
var exports = GlobalContainer.GetExports<IEventAggregator>();
```

But when I try to search the Parts of the composition container I cannot find the duplicate.

```
var parts = this.AggregateCatalog.Parts;

var definitions = new List<ExportDefinition>();
foreach ( var part in parts )
{
    definitions.AddRange( part.ExportDefinitions );
}

definitions.Sort( ( a , b ) => string.Compare( a.ContractName , b.ContractName ) );

var extraDefs = new List<ExportDefinition>();

foreach ( var def in definitions )
{
    if ( def.ContractName.Contains( "EventAggregator" ) )
        extraDefs.Add( def );
}
```

I am using Prism and I need the EventAggregator prior to initialization of Prism. I can add the EventAggregator manually to the container as a CompositionBatch but after Prism is initialized I get an InvalidOperationException because there are two event aggregators. Is there a way to remove the export definition or a way to keep prism from loading its definition. In Prism 4 the MefEventAggregator is done as an export using the AssemblyCatalog so suppressing Prism creation might not be possible. I wanted to view the GetExports source code of the container but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Prism.MefExtensions library and have a `MefBootstrapper`. That library exports the `EventAggregator` for you in this [source file](https://github.com/waynebloss/prism-winforms/blob/master/src/PrismLibrary/Desktop/Prism.MefExtensions/Events/MefEventAggregator.cs)

I can't think of a situation where you'd need the EventAggregator before the bootstrapper is run. Would it be enough to be able to access it there? The MefBootstrapper has the protected Container property that you can use to access the container and get the EventAggregator out.

```
Container.GetExportedValue<IEventAggregator>();
```

I suppose your other option would be to have your export definition as EventAggregator and stay away from the interface to avoid the duplicate.